# Form values from HTML fields to EXT JS using Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: extjs

The project I am trying to build presently has an EXT JS form panel submitting the form using Ext.Ajax.request. Requirement is to create an HTML page and pass the values from the page to the EXTJS form for submitting it. Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a bit confused at what you are doing and why, but if you need to pass extra params to the  server on form submit you can pass them in hte submit method as an object with params key. Like this:

```
myform.submit({ params: { a: 1, b:2}});
```

another option would be to create hidden fields and set their values programmatically.

Comment: :D sorry i got a bit late :) apologies.